# Easeljs is not firing stagemousemove events

Tags: easeljs

Using EaselJs 0.6.0, I am trying to drag my stage around using stagemousedown and stagemousemove events. However, while the mouse down event is being caught correctly, the stage mouse move event does not seem to be fired.

```
var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", tick);
stage.addEventListener("stagemousedown", startDrag);    

// Container to drag around
var dragContainer = new createjs.Container();
stage.addChild(dragContainer);

//..... add stuff onto the stage

// Drag
var offset = new createjs.Point();
function startDrag(event) {
    console.log('startDrag');
    offset.x = stage.mouseX - dragContainer.x;
    offset.y = stage.mouseY - dragContainer.y;
    event.addEventListener("stagemousemove", doDrag);   
}

function doDrag(event) {
    console.log('doDrag');   
    dragContainer.x = event.stageX - offset.x;
    dragContainer.y = event.stageY - offset.y;
}

// Update the stage
function tick(event) {
    stage.update();
}
```

[Here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rboarman/95tJv/2/)

DoDrag is not called. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your fiddle works fine for me, the stage is being dragged. (and I think you are using '0.6' not '1.6' ;P )

Comment: Perhaps the issue is browser related. I'll do some more testing tonight. Thanks!

Comment: I tested with Chrome 33 - what browser are you using?

Comment: Fiddle had an old version of the code based on dragging with a background oject instead of the stage/canvas. Please try again. http://jsfiddle.net/rboarman/95tJv/2/

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why that doesn't work, but I'd do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/95tJv/3/ - this will also work if there is no object below the mouse.

Comment: Works in FF and Chrome, but not in IE9. I'll play around with it later tonight. Thanks!

Comment: I've confirmed that this works in all major brower versions except for IE9.